# Is visible light and radio waves made of the same thing?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, radio

I understand that there is such a thing as the electro magnetic spectrum, and that light and RF are both on it, so dose that mean that they are made of the same thing? Just at different frequencies.

Comment: One thing I'd like to mention: although (as the answers have said) light and radio waves are both electromagnetic waves, it doesn't quite make sense to talk about what those waves are made of, just as it doesn't quite make sense to talk about what an ocean wave is made of. A wave is really just a moving pattern.

Comment: But you wouldn't have an ocean wave if you didn't have H2O, right?

Comment: You already answered it yourself, I cannot realize what is not clear for you. May be there is something deeper in the question?

Comment: An ocean wave is made water molecules, displacement and gravity. A lightwave is made of many photons.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question is Yes.

More specifically, light is 400 to 800 Terahertz, RF is 3 Kilohertz to 300 Gigahertz.

Comment: so those waves (light & RF) would be made of photons?

Comment: Yes, though people don't usually talk of photons for RF, 'cause individual photon energies at that frequency are so small, its not so useful to describe RF waves in terms of photons, but one could do so.

Comment: There are no photon-counting detectors for radio frequencies, one cannot make oscilloscope traces for visible light. But in principle, it is the same thing. And a high speed converts the one into the other by the Doppler effect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are both electromagnetic radiation whose waves are at different frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

you see, the point here is waves are just oscillating energy vectors.

Do you consider a male voice and a female voice as same? Then yes, visible light and RF waves are same!

Its only a matter of how much energy each of them is carrying.

While, RF is having lower photon energy than visible light attributed because of the frequencies.